# Phalcon working with MySQL routines

Tags: phalcon

I have a MySQL database which has GUID's stored as binary(16) for the primary keys. I'm using a MySQL user defined routine when inserting and selecting to convert the id's to and from GUID's (GUIDToBinary() and BinaryToGUID()).

In order to use my routines in Phalcon, I am setting the 'columns' parameter for the find() and findFirst() model functions which now means i'm working with incomplete objects as the functions return an instance of Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Row.

The [docs](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.0.0/reference/models.html#finding-records/) state when using the columns parameter the following occurs;

> Return specific columns instead of the full columns in the model. When
>   using this option an incomplete object is returned

UserController.php

```
// Returns Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Row
$incompleteUser = User::find(['columns' => 'BinaryToGUID(id) as id, status, username, password, .....']);

// Create a new user object to update
$user = new User();

// Populate with existing data
$user->assign($incompleteUser->toArray());

// Assign new changes requested by the user
$user->assign($this->request->getPost());

// Update
$user->updateUser();
```

User.php

```
public function updateUser()
{
        $manager = $this->getModelsManager();

        return $manager->executeQuery("UPDATE User SET ..... WHERE id = GUIDToBinary(".$this->getDI()->get('db')->escapeString($this->id).")");
}
```

Irrespective of the fact that I've explicitly defined an update, an insert is performed due to the Model being in a transient state.

One solution I thought of was to move the binary to GUID conversion into Phalcon by using Model events however I can't find a suitable method for performing the conversion when selecting. Updating/Inserting is possible by using the beforeSave() and beforeUpdate() events. Perhaps I could just have different properties getId() and getIdGuid() within the model but I would prefer to avoid this if possible.

Is there a way to use MySQL user defined routines in Phalcon and hydrate my model so that it remains in a persistent state? Or do i need to go down the raw SQL route for my updates and avoid PHQL?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: *"Perhaps I could just have different properties getId() and getIdGuid() within the model but I would prefer to avoid this if possible."* Why? If you generate the model with phalcon developer tools, it will set these methods up, then you can modify the data with the setters, then call `$user->save()` to save the object back to the database with PHQL (which will update the user record with the class properties you modify with the setters)

Comment: Thanks. I left one thing out of my initial post. I need the Id of the model in both states - GUID for the client and binary for the DB.